# Не получается сортировка

Tags: java, сортировка

Имею такую задачу:

На вход получаю список названий книг.
Распределить книги так, чтобы на каждой полке было примерно одинаковое кол-во книг.
Книги должны быть отсортированы по алфавиту с первой и до последней полки.
Количество полок константное 5 штук.
Вернуть книги распределенные по полкам

```
private static List<ArrayList<Book>> getShelvesOfBooks(List<Book> books){

        List<Book> sortedBooks = books.stream()
                                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Book::getName))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<ArrayList<Book>> shelves = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Book> shelf1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Book> shelf2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Book> shelf3 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Book> shelf4 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Book> shelf5 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedBooks.size(); i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 0){
                shelf1.add(sortedBooks.get(i));
            }
            if (i % 5 == 1){
                shelf2.add(sortedBooks.get(i));

            }
            if (i % 5 == 2){
                shelf3.add(sortedBooks.get(i));

            }
            if (i % 5 == 3){
                shelf4.add(sortedBooks.get(i));

            }
            if (i % 5 == 4){
                shelf5.add(sortedBooks.get(i));

            }
        }

        shelves.add(shelf1);
        shelves.add(shelf2);
        shelves.add(shelf3);
        shelves.add(shelf4);
        shelves.add(shelf5);

        return shelves;
    }
```

В этом случае книжки отсортированы по алфавиту, но становятся на полках не в том порядке, как мне надо.

```
shelf1 = [Book[name='Java в действии'], Book[name='Повесть о настоящем человеке']]
shelf2 = [Book[name='Аэропорт'], Book[name='Сказки']]
shelf3 = [Book[name='Война и мир'], Book[name='Собака Баскервилей']]
shelf4 = [Book[name='Игра престолов'], Book[name='Том Сойер']]
shelf5 = [Book[name='Мастер и Маргарита'], Book[name='Цитадель']]
```

Как сделать, чтобы после сортировки был следующий порядок

```
shelf1 = [Book[name='Java в действии'], [name='Аэропорт']]
shelf2 = [Book[name='Война и мир'], Book[name='Игра престолов']]
shelf3 = [Book[name='Мастер и Маргарита'], Book[name='Повесть о настоящем человеке']]
...
```

Алгоритм действий будет другой. Сортировать наверное надо на лету, перед вставкой книги на полку. Только не могу понять, как этого добиться и ещё чтобы было примерно одинаковое число книг на каждой полке. Когда число книг не кратно 5, то добавление должно быть с первой полки. То есть, если книг 7, то на первой и второй полках будет по две книги, а на остальных по одной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прямо заранее не получится какую то константу книг для каждой полки расчитать иначе первые полки могут быть битком заполнены, а последние пустые.

Потому я предлагаю пересчитывать количество книг для каждой полки перед тем, как туда что то ставить.

Пример

```
private static List<ArrayList<String>> getShelvesOfBooks(List<String> books) {

    books = books.stream()
                 .sorted()
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<ArrayList<String>> shelves = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ArrayList<String> shelf = new ArrayList<>();
        shelves.add(shelf);
    }

    int ind = 0;
    int shelfInd = 0;

    while (ind < books.size()) {
        int perShelf = getBooksPerShelf(books.size() - ind, shelves.size() - shelfInd);
        for (int i = 0; i < perShelf; i++) {
            shelves.get(shelfInd).add(books.get(ind));
            ind++;
        }
        shelfInd++;
    }

    return shelves;
}
```

Подсчет книг на полку элементарный

```
static int getBooksPerShelf(int books, int shelves) {
    int perShelf = books / shelves;
    if (perShelf * shelves < books)
        perShelf++;
    return perShelf;
}
```

Проверка

```
    List<String> books = new ArrayList<>();
    books.add("Java в действии");
    books.add("Повесть о настоящем человеке");
    books.add("Аэропорт");
    books.add("Сказки");
    books.add("Война и мир");
    books.add("Собака Баскервилей");
    books.add("Игра престолов");
    books.add("Том Сойер");
    books.add("Мастер и Маргарита");
    books.add("Цитадель");
    books.add("Цитадель");

    List<ArrayList<String>> ret = getShelvesOfBooks(books);

    ret.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод

```
[Java в действии, Аэропорт, Война и мир]
[Игра престолов, Мастер и Маргарита]
[Повесть о настоящем человеке, Сказки]
[Собака Баскервилей, Том Сойер]
[Цитадель, Цитадель]
```

Comment: tym32167, спасибо за помощь в решении !

Comment: Если помогло, то галочка где то слева от ответа :)

Comment: tym32167, забыл сразу поставить )))

Answer (score 1):

В комментах упомянули второй вариант решения. Штош.

Идея в том, чтобы посчитать сначала сколько точно будет книг на каждой полке. А потом остатки книг просто расставить по одной на полке.

Код будет чутка короче соседнего моего ответа

```
private static List<ArrayList<String>> getShelvesOfBooks(List<String> books) {

    books = books.stream()
                 .sorted()
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<ArrayList<String>> shelves = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ArrayList<String> shelf = new ArrayList<>();
        shelves.add(shelf);
    }

    int ind = 0;

    int perShelf = books.size() / shelves.size();
    int remainder = books.size() % shelves.size();

    for (List<String> shelve : shelves) {
        for (int i = 0; i < perShelf; i++)
            shelve.add(books.get(ind++));
        if (remainder-- > 0)
            shelve.add(books.get(ind++));
    }

    return shelves;
}
```

Проверка

```
    List<String> books = new ArrayList<>();
    books.add("Java в действии");
    books.add("Повесть о настоящем человеке");
    books.add("Аэропорт");
    books.add("Сказки");
    books.add("Война и мир");
    books.add("Собака Баскервилей");
    books.add("Игра престолов");
    books.add("Том Сойер");
    books.add("Мастер и Маргарита");
    books.add("Цитадель");
    books.add("Цитадель");

    List<ArrayList<String>> ret = getShelvesOfBooks(books);

    ret.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод

```
[Java в действии, Аэропорт, Война и мир]
[Игра престолов, Мастер и Маргарита]
[Повесть о настоящем человеке, Сказки]
[Собака Баскервилей, Том Сойер]
[Цитадель, Цитадель]
```

Comment: Мне стало немного неловко и я решил преобразовать комментарий в ответ, но ваш вариант получше т.к. у меня StreamApi для расчетов и будет не так быстро.

Comment: У вас да, чуть сложнее читать код. Ну и сам код будет медленней, так как его сложность будет О(полки * книги), у меня же О(полки + книги) - я так подумал, потому что вроде skip операция не константная.

Comment: По идее со skip не должно быть проблем, документация говорит это дешёвая операция, хотя внутрь я не заглядывал. Но вот лишние вызовы, проверки и преобразования дадут о себе знать.

Comment: я тож не заглядывал, чисто предположил. Ну ещё как микрооптимизацию, можно список с книгами для полок не пересоздавать. А то сначала книги в один список складываются, потом в другой - памяти в итоге в 2 раза больше тратится =) Но если skip константный, то асимптотика один фиг будет во всех ответах одинаковая.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы заранее посчитал, сколько книг на полке `int bookPerShelf = sortedBooks.size() / shelves.size()` и сколько полок надо дополнить `int shelfWithExtraBook = sortedBooks.size() % shelves.size()`.

Примерно получим, что 17 / 5 = 3 - на каждой полке по три книги и 17 % 5 = 2 - на первых двух полках добавить еще по +1 книге. А дальше только расставить нужное кол-во на каждую полку по порядку.

```
private static List<ArrayList<Book>> getShelvesOfBooks(List<Book> books){
    var sortedBooks = books.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Book::getName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    var shelves = IntStream
            .range(0,5)
            .mapToObj(x -> new ArrayList<Book>())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    int bookPerShelf = sortedBooks.size() / shelves.size();
    int shelfWithExtraBook = sortedBooks.size() % shelves.size();

    int skip = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < shelves.size(); i++) {
        var limit = bookPerShelf + (i + 1 <= shelfWithExtraBook ? 1 : 0);
        var currentBooks = sortedBooks.stream()
                .skip(skip)
                .limit(limit)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        skip += limit;
        shelves.get(i).addAll(currentBooks);
    }

    return shelves;
}
```